# Huawei Settlement Process

Tags: payment, huawei-mobile-services

Huawei application whose profits reached more than 300 euros and two months have passed since this profit, but I cannot withdraw it because there is no data in the Credited section

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. The OP should contact Huawei

Answer (score 0):

On the 15th day of any Settlement Period Huawei shall provide you settlement sheets. **For example**, Huawei will provide you with the settlement details for May on June 15.
After you have confirmed a settlement sheet and Huawei has approved it, the status of the settlement sheet on the settlement page will change to in payment, **payment will be made within thirty (30) calendar days.**
However, if your accumulated transaction amount to be settled for a settlement period from a single **signing entity** is under the maximum amount (CNY1000 for products distributed in the Chinese mainland and EUR200 for products distributed outside the Chinese mainland), the settlement date will be postponed until the date when the amount reaches the maximum. If the amount fails to reach the maximum in six months, Huawei will settle the amount that has accumulated within those six months.

For more info, please refer to the FAQ of Settlement and the Self-service Settlement Guide.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/help/settlement-0000001052983076

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/start/40101